# Alexa not always responding to questions

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have a skill in beta which works occassionally with Alexa. When I say

Alexa ask MySkill....

She sometimes responds and sometimes says

"sorry I dont know that one" or "sorry I;m not sure"

My lambda logs dont contain anything which implies lambda is not being called. Are there any other logs I can look at to see what is happening?

My invocation name is two words so I'm wondering if Alexa is sometimes hearing it as one and then not finding the intent.

Thanks

Comment: What is the invocation name and the utterances? Having two words as invocation is quite common. Ensure your invocation name is not used in your utterance. I have had problems when the invocation name was used in one of my utterances.

Comment: Also, be sure to follow the guidelines in the choiche of the invocation name, foreign names or common names can be misunderstood.
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/choose-the-invocation-name-for-a-custom-skill.html

Comment: set some "console.log(..)" in your Lambda and check CloudWatch.

Comment: "Sorry I don't know that one" response points that the skill was not invoked. Check your invocation name and make sure it triggers the skill.